# SugarCRM CE TextArea Display Single Row of Data

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm trying to make a TextArea field in the Opportunities module show only a single row of data then allow the user to scroll through the remaining data. How can this be done?

I have looked this up here on Stack Overflow but cannot seem to make this work.

I am using *SugarCRM CE version 6.5.13*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create the file if it doesn't already exist:

**custom/modules/Opportunities/metadata/editviewdefs.php**

Within the edit view definition file you can use `displayParams` to change or add attributes to a specific field. For instance, I added the attribute 'rows' and made it 1 row (it can still expand).

```
       6 => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'name' => 'description',
            'label' => 'LBL_DESCRIPTION',
            'displayParams' => 
            array (
              'rows' => 1,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Hope this helps.